# Unable to parse template "Class" Error whenever I try to open a new java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I'm doing an Android Studio project (from this tutorial here: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-2-setting-up-libgdx.html).

When I press New Java Class I'm getting the error that's described in the title:

> Unable to parse template "Class" Error message: This template did not
>   produce a Java class or an interface.

I don't know why. I've searched on this site, there doesn't seem to be an answer.

There are No error messages in the code.

For what it is worth, I recently updated the gradle version for android studio before. 
Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: backup your .AndroidStudio directory, delete it. And configure everything from scratch.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: I mean I know how but I'm wondering where the .androidstudio directory is located.

Comment: Depends on your operating system, don't you know how to find a directory?

Comment: I mean I do for pretty much everything else. I use Windows. Is it under C:/Users/username/AndroidStudio2.3 ? Or like C:/User/ProgramFiles/ ? That's what I was asking.

Comment: c:\users\username\.AndroidStudio2.3

Comment: Thanks, I figured. I actually already solved the issue by editing the file template. Do you know what causes this issue to happen though? is it just a bug/glitch?

Comment: Don't know. Glad you fixed it.

Comment: For those who are still not able to fix. In android studio 2017, Go to File->setting->editor->file and code templates, select Class in the files tab and paste this #if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} {
}

Comment: The reason is you maybe installed the 64 bit version on a 32 bit machine. I had the same problem.