# Can't I add a new Java class while using an activity template in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, templates, authentication, splash-screen

So, I made a new Android project with the default sign in activity. Since then, I have made some changes to GUI through the XML. But then, when I tried to add a new Java class. [I have encountered this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVCZH.jpg) 
 I haven't added any new Java code to the template before doing so before, since starting this project. 
I looked around this site for a solution.

[This one talked about a bug. But doesn't seem like a bug to me. This question was closed because it was off-topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534524/unable-to-parse-template-class-error-whenever-i-try-to-open-a-new-java-class)

[This one is similar to my problem because I don't think coding is the problem, but it the question was closed due to ambiguity.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577463/unable-to-parse-template-class-error-message-this-template-did-not-produce-a)

So it is the same problem, but a different cause.

UPDATE 8/15/17

I did what *star4z* recommended. I made a new Android project with the default sign in activity template. That's all I did. I didn't do any XML changes at all this time. Then, as soon as I added a new Java class, [I encountered the same error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVCZH.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Android Studio and I was facing exactly the same error after I upgraded to java 8.
I resolved it by going through menu options in Android Studio.

help>Edit custom VM (If Android studion asks you the permission to creat this file, select YES).

It will open a file named **studio64.exe.vmoptions** then add below line in the file.

-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false

Finally go to file and select Invalidate cache/restart and you are good to go.

It seems to pe an error resolved by oracle to the Java 8 Update 144.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File->setting->editor->file and code templates, select Class in the files tab and write this:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "" &&    ${Is_your_class_abstract_Reply_yes_no} == "no")
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};
#parse("File Header.java") public class ${NAME} {

}
#elseif (${Is_your_class_abstract_Reply_yes_no} == "yes")
#parse("File Header.java") public abstract class ${NAME} {

}
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing: "But then, when I tried to add a new Java class" seems to be missing its second half.

I think your question is analogous to the first reference you posted based on the screenshot. You appear to be creating a class the proper way; it would be impossible to figure out the source of the problem without someone looking at everything in your project and editor, though I suspect some files got deleted that shouldn't have at some point.

I would suggest starting a new project and copying the changes you've made to files in this project over.